# Essa pergunta faz parte do escopo?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

A pergunta [Cobrança de Tráfego em Sistema SaaS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80218/cobran%C3%A7a-de-tr%C3%A1fego-em-sistema-saas) faz parte do escopo? O autor pergunta de forma generalizada (como se existisse uma norma) sobre cobrança de serviço SaaS e ainda oferece uma recompensa. Qual opinião de vocês?

Answer (score 3):

Achei "**pertinente**" a dúvida, se esta no escopo já jé outra coisa....rsrsr o SOPT aceita muita coisa "fora do escopo" pré-estabelecido através de **votações**, tudo depende, acho que nesse caso a comunidade toda se beneficia com a dúvida/reposta então eu votaria para manter ela aberta mesmo se o "**escopo**" não incluí-la.